# Logging into Stack Overflow with cURL

Tags: shell, curl, sh

I'm working on a project and I want to log into Stack Overflow via cURL.

I use Google as my openID provider which means that I need to log into Google first via its API.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
. ./params.sh #the script with $username and $password
curl --silent https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin \
-d Email=$username -d Passwd=$password \
-d accountType=GOOGLE \
-d source=localhost-test-1 \
-d service=lso \
-o tokens
. ./tokens
echo $Auth; #$Auth is correct here - I did not get a BadAuth error.

endpoint="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id";

curl http://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate \
    -d "openid_identifier=$endpoint" \
    -w %{redirect_url}> ./google_url
google_url=$(cat ./google_url);
echo $google_url;
echo;
echo;
echo;
curl -L --silent --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$Auth" $google_url;
```

At this point I get a page from Google telling me that Stack Overflow wants information and I have to log in. According to [this page](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/using_cURL.html), the `--header ... $Auth` part should count as a login and redirect me to Stack Overflow.

Here is the form I get when I run this script:

```
<form id="gaia_universallogin"
      action="https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?service=lso" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="continue" id="continue"
           value="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?st=SOME_KEY" />
  <input type="hidden" name="service" id="service"
           value="lso" />
  <input type="hidden" name="dsh" id="dsh"
           value="SOME_NEG_NUMBER" />
</form>
```

When I try the answer below I get the following error:

```
    Can't call method "attr" on an undefined value at - line 8.
    curl: (3) <url> malformed
--></style>
```

here is the output from `google2.html`

```
<form id="gaia_loginform"      
        action="https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?service=lso" method="post"                >
  <input type="hidden" name="continue" id="continue"            value="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?st=RNADOM" />
  <input type="hidden" name="service" id="service"            value="lso" />
  <input type="hidden" name="dsh" id="dsh"            value="NEG_NUMEBER" />
  <input type="hidden"              name="GALX"             value="ABCD" />
  <input type="text" name="Email"  id="Email" />
  <input type="password"   name="Passwd" id="Passwd" > 
  <input type="checkbox" name="PersistentCookie" id="PersistentCookie"    value="yes"
  <input type="hidden" name='rmShown' value="1" />
  <input type="submit" class="gaia le button" name="signIn" id="signIn"                 />
<input type="hidden" name="asts"    >
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing curl's UserAgent?

Comment: ZyX - For what reason would I have the change the UA? At this point it isn't even logging in let alone giving me UA specific code.

Comment: it might have a security feature of not allowing you to login with a php user agent...

Comment: True - although I recently found a HOWTO from google on how to login using curl ;)
Now I just need the SO part...

Comment: Try adding some "echo" statements to find out where the errors are coming from. The "curl" error probably means the URL it's asking for is empty, and the "undefined value" error probably means that the HTML element/attribute it's looking for isn't there - which may mean you're getting a different response back from Google from what I got... let us know what you find!

Comment: *cough* fanatic badge *cough*

Comment: OK - the `googleform.html` output looks fine :) What about `google2.html` & `google3.html`? I would expect the problem to be in `google2.html`...

Comment: @psmears: I added the google2.html stuff

Comment: Thanks! That looks like it's sent you back the login form again. If you look at the whole of that file (eg. load it in your browser), do you see any errors? Is it possible the username or password are incorrect? (For comparison, I get a doc that just contains (roughly): `<script>...</script><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="XXX"><script>...</script>` where the XXX is a Google URL that, when the next curl loads it, finally logs in to SO...

Comment: @psmears: I finally got it to work. It seems like it was an interment Google problem. Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: @psmears: given the amount of help you gave me I wish I could give you more rep ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Google login service is specific to the particular service you're using (Google docs vs Google Analytics vs Google Maps etc). The service ode you've specified (lh2) is specific to Google Picasa.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an equivalent code for OpenId (at least, not that I could find!)

The page that you get back from Google should contain a login form. If you look at that, it should be possible to construct a curl invocation to log in; that should then redirect you back to SO (or whichever openID page you want to log in to) logged in.

It turns out that doing this is a little tricky, because you have to parse out some of the the form fields to submit them back to Google, and because Google doesn't send back a straight HTTP redirect, but an HTML doc with a `<meta http-equiv="redirect" ...>` tag. And of course you have to enable cookies. But this is all possible in a script using curl - the following works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Utility function for parsing values out of an HTML form
get_value()
{
    local tagtype="$1" attrname="$2" attrvalue="$3" getattr="$4"
    perl -MHTML::TreeBuilder - "$@" <<EOF
         @args=@ARGV;
         \$h=HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
         \$h->parse_file("$htmlfile");
         while (\$#args > 0) {
             \$h=\$h->look_down(_tag => shift @args,
                                shift @args => shift @args);
         }
         print \$h->attr(shift @args);
EOF
}

# Empty the cookie jar
cj="cookiejar"
rm -f "$cj"

# Attempt to log in to SO. This will redirect to a google URL.
endpoint="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"

google_url=`curl -L -s -S http://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate \
    -d "openid_identifier=$endpoint" \
    -o /dev/null -b "$cj" -c "$cj" \
    -w %{url_effective}`
echo $google_url
echo
echo

# Retrieve the form from Google
htmlfile=googleform.html
curl -L -s -S -o "$htmlfile" -b "$cj" -c "$cj" "$google_url"

# Parse out the form fields
form_url=`get_value form id gaia_loginform action`

fdsh=`get_value form id gaia_loginform input name dsh value`
fcontinue=`get_value form id gaia_loginform input name continue value`
fservice=`get_value form id gaia_loginform input name service value`
fGALX=`get_value form id gaia_loginform input name GALX value`
frmShown=`get_value form id gaia_loginform input name rmShown value`
fsignIn=`get_value form id gaia_loginform input name signIn value`

fEmail='INSERT LOGIN EMAIL HERE'
fPasswd='INSERT PASSWORD HERE'

# Submit the login form
htmlfile=google2.html
curl -L -s -S -o "$htmlfile" -b "$cj" -c "$cj" --data-urlencode dsh="$fdsh" \
  --data-urlencode continue="$fcontinue" \
  --data-urlencode service="$fservice" \
  --data-urlencode GALX="$fGALX" \
  --data-urlencode Email="$fEmail" \
  --data-urlencode Passwd="$fPasswd" \
  --data-urlencode rmShown="$frmShown" \
  --data-urlencode signIn="$fsignIn" \
  "$form_url"

# Interpret the redirect
redirect=`get_value meta http-equiv refresh content | sed "s/^.*'\(.*\)'.*$/\1/"`

# Follow it
htmlfile=google3.html
curl -L -s -S -o "$htmlfile" -b "$cj" -c "$cj" "$redirect"
```

(Note that I seem to have a slightly different version of curl from you, so I had to change the `-w` options slightly; I'm guessing my version will work for you but you may need to tweak it.)

Comment: I found the service code in the form and I changed my code above to match it ("lso"). However this still doesn't log in.

Comment: What I meant was, submit the form itself using curl... if you post the content of that form (just the contents of the FORM tag) it might be possible to provide further hints...

Comment: Also - NEVER use "/bin/bash" - instead use "/usr/bin/env bash" as different OSs may not have bash in /bin.

Comment: You don't have to use perl - that's just one way of parsing out the data. There are plenty of others to choose from :). But the above should at least give you the right idea of what to do, right?

Comment: (The trouble with using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is that is uses the user's `PATH` setting to find the program; if that includes a pointer to an older version of bash than your script was designed for, your script will fail :( And in fact there do exist systems where `/usr/bin/env` doesn't exist, only `/bin/env` :( In practice the best choice will depend on the environment the script will be installed/run in - usually I'm writing scripts for systems where I can guarantee what will be installed, but where the users' `PATH`s often contain crazy stuff - so `#!/bin/bash` is best for me :)

Comment: /bin/bash fails for me: its installed in /usr/local/bin/bash. with /usr/bin/env it will work on the most possible systems. I know there are exceptions but in working with solaris, *bsd, linux distros, and many other OSes I've NEVER seen /usr/bin/env missing.

Comment: Fair enough - use whatever works best in your situation :) As I've said, /usr/bin/env has issues for me, that /bin/bash doesn't - so I'll keep using that :)

Comment: can someone explain what I have to do to utilize this script? Is this one file? Is it .sh file etc? Will really appreicate